# Manjaro KDE: infinite splash screen when logging in to active account

Tags: linux, kde, manjaro

When I go to the login screen via SUPER + L and enter my password I can get back into my system normally.

When I click "Switch User" from the login screen and then log into the previous, still active account, then the splash screen pops up and I am stuck.

I am new to all this Linux business, so any advice would be appreciated.